# How To Make Transparent Background In Any Text Editor Like Sublime?

Tags: text, background, text-editor, transparent

I want to make a transparent background in Text Editor,Like Sublime I want to text while reading text on youtube.

Comment: Search for "WindowTop"
It have paid feature called "Glass" and it will do exactly what you asked for.
It will make *only* the background transparent as you asked and keep the text without any transparency.

Note that it will work only on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature varies in different editors. You can check in Preferences if they allow that

Comment: But Any Package or Theme You Can Suggest I Still Not Find Any Type Of Transparent Background

Comment: Sublime, Linux text Editor, Visual Studio Code

Comment: If you are using Sublime Text, there is a package manager - https://packagecontrol.io/
You can find transparent here, it is a package on github. Will help in your issue
https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/669/how-to-make-the-visual-studio-code-window-transparent-in-windows - This might help for Visual Studio

Comment: Thanks For Your Help And I Also Got A Solution From YouTube     https://youtu.be/mBwA2Z90liE

Comment: This Is For Only Windows User But, I Am Using Linux

Answer (score 0):

I am on a Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon machine and my search for a solution lead me to Micro ( https://micro-editor.github.io/ ) and Nano (in package repository).

Micro is a text editor running in a Terminal which with an appropriate color scheme (with not set default background/foreground color) inherits the background transparency from the GNOME Terminal.

The transparency doesn't work 100% of the time (showing desktop background in spite of opened windows covering it),so sometimes the Terminal or Micro must be restarted to keep the proper functioning of the transparency, but most of the time it works as expected allowing to read through it while typing.

Currently Micro and Nano are the only text editors known to me that are open source and free and come with such feature.